Why do the people at the Cave react this way to Orpheus's actions?
In the series Kaos, there is a bar where people can play trivia for the chance to retrieve someone from the Underworld. Obviously, neither the patrons nor anyone else knows about the true purpose of the Frame, and they likely do not know that it exists. However, they do know that the official Olympian religion teaches that if one has a coin to pay one's passage, one will be reincarnated in a (hopefully good) life, so it seems logical to expect that if someone did have a coin, they would already have been processed.
Furthermore, almost everyone seems to be there to either have a chance at retrieving a lost loved one, or to cheer on a "team," so they already are very much on board with the idea of doing desperate things against the alleged laws of nature to bring someone back from the Underworld, of which keeping someone's coin would seem an almost necessary first step.
With that in mind, why does everyone at the bar—including the other teams—act surprised and disgusted that Orpheus would keep Eurydice's coin?
